# How to update an @Embedded field

Tags: morphia, updating

I'm using Morphia 0.99 and I'm trying to update an embedded field in an entity, but I don't see how.

```
// User entity
@Entity(value = "users", noClassnameStored = true)
public class User
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Embedded
    private UserConfig userConfig;
}

// User DAO
public class UserDao extends BasicDAO <User, ObjectId> implements IUserDao
{
    @Override
    public void setConfig (String userId, UserConfig config)
    {
        User user = get (new ObjectId (userId));
        user.setNotificationsTypes (notitypes);
        "this.update(user);"
    }
}
```

[This page](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating) suggests something this:

```
// User DAO
public class UserDao extends BasicDAO <User, ObjectId> implements IUserDao
{
    @Override
    public void setConfig (String userId, UserConfig config)
    {
        Query <User> query = ds.createQuery (User.class).field (idString).equal (userId);
        UpdateOperations <User> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations (User.class).set ("userConfig.someField", "Some Value");
        ds.update (updateQuery, ops);
    }
}
```

But I want to update the whole embedded field, not each subfield one by one. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Either use an update on a specific field (or multiple ones) or persist the whole object again (in your case on the User class) - persist will do an upsert.

Comment: But what is the code for that? These two didn't work:

    Query <User> query = ds.createQuery(User.class).field (idString).equal (userId);
    UpdateOperations <User> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations (User.class)
        .set ("userConfig.field1", value1)
        .set ("userConfig.field2", value2)
    ds.update (query, ops);

Comment: The other option that didn't work is:

    UpdateOperations <User> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations (User.class).set ("userConfig", config);
    ds.update (query, ops);

Comment: ``ds.save(user);`` - if ``user._id`` is empty a new document will be created (and the database will generate your ID), if there is an ID the document with it will be updated.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried this code:

    User user = get (new ObjectId (userId));
    user.setUserConfig (config);
    this.save (user);

When I execute that, I get this

Error E11000: duplicate error index: mydb.users.$username_1 dup key: {: "Andrew"}

Andrew is the test username, which is a unique attribute of User.

Comment: Somewhat is off with your ``_id``. You should use ``ObjectId`` for ``@Id`` in general, but for this scenario a string should work as well. Are you sure ``new ObjectId (userId)`` is behaving as you expect?

Comment: Don't ask me why, but we have been using String in all entities and ObjectId in the DAOs. T tried to convert the UserDao from <User, ObjectId> to <User, String>, but the this.get() method stopped working. I'll try to change the entity to ObjectId. But how will I use the class outside the server, where there's no Morphia? I think that's the reason why we use String for the identifiers.

Comment: I can't change the entity to ObjectId, it breaks several other pieces of code. There must be a solution with the current scheme.

Comment: Let's go back to square one. Since I'll show the actual log, I'll paste the actual code I tried to execute:

/**/ Query <User> query = ds.createQuery(User.class).field (idString).equal (userId);
UpdateOperations <User> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(User.class).set ("notificationsTypes", notitypes);
ds.update (query, ops); /**/

Comment: The Mongo log says this: /**/ {
"ts" : ISODate("2012-11-06T22:56:31.477Z"),
"op" : "update",
"ns" : "geouy.users",
"query" : {
"_id" : "50998e930000bc3b6d20bf5a"
},
"updateobj" : {
"$set" : {
"notificationsTypes" : {
"notitype1_contactsVisits" : true,
"notitype2_contactsComments" : false
}
}
},
"nscanned" : 0,
"nupdated" : 0,
"keyUpdates" : 0,
"numYield" : 0,
"lockStats" : {
"timeLockedMicros" : {
"r" : NumberLong(0),
"w" : NumberLong(126)
},
"timeAcquiringMicros" : {
"r" : NumberLong(0),
"w" : NumberLong(9)
}
},
"millis" : 0,
"client" : "192.168.2.2",
"user" : ""
}/**/

Comment: The values of the user are these: /**/ { "_id" : ObjectId("50998e930000bc3b6d20bf5a"),
"userName" : "Agustin",
"notificationsTypes" : {
"notitype1_contactsVisits" : false,
"notitype2_contactsComments" : false,
"roles" : [ "REG_USER" ] } /**/

So I tried to set notitype1_contactsVisits to true, but the entre remains at false. As you can see, the id is the same. What's the issue?

Comment: I found the answer: I had to type "equal (new ObjectId (userId))". So Morphia isn't that much type safe :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually it is: ``"_id" : "50998e930000bc3b6d20bf5a"`` != ``"_id" : ObjectId("50998e930000bc3b6d20bf5a")``
We are using ObjectIds for internal use and an additional, unique UUID which is exposed externally

Comment: Morphia's query system allowed me to try to compare an ObjectId with a String. It didn't show a compile error or throw a runtime error, the query resulted in a no match. That's what I mean by saying Morphia isn't type-safe. Bye!